# Create triggers VS backend queries, Performance and Resource

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm working with **javascript** back end (**nodejs runtime**) and MySQL database. So far as my db grew up, my `triggers` and my `pool` is working normally, but it still in small user environment. For the future of my app, I'm wondering about the server resources and server performance, because so many tables that need trigger actions.

Eg. -> After Insert a row in `table_a` I have to update a field in my `table_b`.

So, [1] what is the best way to provide data with my `back end`? Using `back end queries` or creating a MySQL `triggers`?

[2] how about `back end pool queries` vs `MySQL triggers` performance?

[3] what is more affordable resource between `back end pool queries` vs `MySQL triggers`?

thanks in advance.

Comment: *After Insert a field in table_a I have to update my table_b.* Do you insert one row, or you insert huge array of rows?

Comment: oh sorry, I'll edit my question

Comment: I mean, after insert a row in `table1` I have to update a field at my `table2`

Comment: not huge array of row, just a row. but so many table need it. so what is the best way?

Comment: For single row the trigger will give better performance. But you must remember that if you update 1st table, trigger fires and updates 2nd table, this change will not fire trigger on 2nd table for to alter 3rd table data.

Comment: can you explain me why ?